# How to extract diagonal elements from dataframe and store in a variable?

Tags: r

I have a simple 9 element dataframe.

```
  A  B  C
1  8 21  1
2 40 25 32
3 10 15 49
```

I want to extract the diagonal elements and store it in a variable. Is there an easier way to do this other than taking one number out at a time to store to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case as they are all numeric you can use:

`df <- data.frame(a=c(4,8,10), b = c(25,24,15), c = c(1,32,49))`
df

> df
>      a  b  c
>   1  4 25  1
>   2  8 24 32
>   3 10 15 49

Where this takes the diagonal.
`diag(as.matrix(df))`

[1]  4 24 49

Comment: So I had this question initially, I know 4,24,49 are diagonal. Should 10 and 1 also be included in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `diag` function which extracts the diagonal of a matrix:

```
Data <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b= c(11,12,13), c = c(111,112,113))
Data2 <- as.matrix(Data)
Result <- diag(Data2)
Result #Returns 1  12 113
```